# How can I get auto suggestion for jQuery in Dreamweaver?

Tags: jquery, dreamweaver, cs3

I am using Dreamweaver CS3. I would like auto suggestion and auto complete features for JavaScript and jQuery like for HTML and CSS.

Comment: Please give example of some code where you wanna use autocomplete

Comment: @AkselWillgert  comment makes no sense, OP is asking about code type ahead in an editor for the whole library

Comment: Yeh i missunderstood. Thougt it was about implementing autocomplete func. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extension for it in the extensions library on Adobe site but it doesn't work very well. I say this based on my experiences with DW CS3 from years ago, I doubt updates have been made for CS3 extensions but could be wrong. Suggest using `Sublime Text` with jQuery plugin and javascript formatting plugin as javascript editor. Infinitely better than older versions of Dreamweaver.

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl Now I am using `Sublime Text` and it's far better.